# Related List not showing records on Parent Object

Tags: lookup, related-list, sharepoint, files-connect

I'm having an issue populating records in my related list. As you can see below, it is empty.
[image: Parent to Child Link]

[image]

I've linked my custom salesforce object(parent) to my SharePoint external object(child) via an indirect lookup relationship.

On my Salesforce Parent Object, I've created an External Id called sharepointid.
[image: externalId]

On the SharePoint external child object, I've created an indirect lookup referencing my parent file object via an the external id.
[image: External Object Properties]

When I edit my SharePoint file's sharepointid to match my parent object's external ID, my child object successfully has a link to the parent via the indirect lookup relationship.
[image: Child To Parent Link]

The parent's related list however, is still empty... The child references/maps to the parent fine, but the parent doesn't map the to child. Am I missing a step? Since the child maps to to the parent I assume the reverse relationship is also automatically created.

I'm on lightning experience, but the issue persists in classic as well. Note that I've integrated SharePoint files via Files Connect. I can search and view my SharePoint files on salesforce successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!